Problems with unity tutorial
I recently started teaching unity guides from their website. Today, during the next lesson, I had a problem. The "player" cannot take the object. My code is identical to the code from the site, but the problem is still there. How can this problem be solved?
My code:

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other) 
    {
 
 if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("PickUp")) 
        {
 
            other.gameObject.SetActive(false);

 
            count++;

 
            SetCountText();
        }
    }
}

As I understand it, the problem is in this function. Although it completely repeats the one that was shown in the guide

You're teaching Unity, or learning it?

What do you mean by 'The "player" cannot take the object'? Please provide the precise error message, and show which line it's on.

I'm making a Roll-a-Ball game based on a tutorial from the official unity website. One of the lessons tells you how to make the ball (player) He could collect an object and thereby increase the number of points scored

Youre gonna need to show a [mcve] of how to setup a minimal enough code and environment to reproduce

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

You sure the tag is correct and assigned to the object you want to pick up? Have you tried to out some Debug.Log to see if the method is called at all?

The problem may be that you need to add them the tag "PickUp" or a problem with the colliders setup.
